How is this detent ratchet mechanism is called
At my work, we have a ratchet ring that we call a clicker disk.
In my search on the internet I have not been able to find the name of this mechanism that has the teeth on the sides of the circumference, unlike conventional ratchets that have them around the circumference.
I am interested in designing a system that uses 2 of these ratchet rings and rotates against each other on the same axis.



what does the patent documentation call it?

What you've shown appears to be a modified Hirth coupling or Hirth joint. I searched for ratcheting Hirth joint and came up mostly empty. There's a Reddit post from a year ago in which the OP also had zero results. I'm quite surprised at this zero result, especially since 3D printing makes Hirth joint creation that much easier for hobbyists.

the mechanism is similar to the one used in hammer drills

'Ratchet' is the correct name. Typically, one will be labeled the 'driver ratchet' and the other the 'driven ratchet'. 'Ratchet disc' might also be a proper name.
